# How to make my package publicly available?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a ROS package for the yoctopuce altimeter. I'm fairly certain it's the only form of ROS support for the altimeter, and I would like to make it publicly available via the ROS website. How do I go about doing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282786/how-to-make-my-package-publicly-available?/) by [amstrudy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31757/amstrudy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-02-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is nicely covered by [wiki/Get Involved: Create Your Own ROS package Repository](http://wiki.ros.org/Get%20Involved#Create_Your_Own_ROS_package_Repository) and the subsequent section *Release Binary Packages*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amstrudy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31757/amstrudy/) on 2018-02-14**:
Thank you! I was looking for something like this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Btw: this doesn't make your pkg any more 'official' than others, but it does make it available to other users for installation using `apt-get`.